# How to upload multiple images/files in Flutter using Dio?

Tags: flutter, dio

I have been trying to upload multiple images/files to the backend in Flutter. I am using `Dio`.
So far, I have not been able to do so.

I have been able to do so using postman. This is the form-data

[image: Request made from Postman]

This is my code:

```
    Future<dynamic> fileUpload(List<String> filepath, String url) async {
    var token = await storage.getToken();
    var idToken = await storage.getIdToken();
    Dio dio = Dio();

    List uploadList = [];
    for (var file in filepath) {
      var multipartFile = await MultipartFile.fromFile(
        file
      );
      uploadList.add(multipartFile);
    }

    FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({"assignment": uploadList});
     var response = await dio.post(APIURL.baseUrl + url,
        data: formData,
        options: Options(headers: {
          HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer $token",
          'idToken': idToken,
        }));
    return response;
  }
```

Can somebody please help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Turns out there are two ways to add multiple files to FormData. The following approach worked

```
var formData = FormData();
for (var file in filepath) {
  formData.files.addAll([
  MapEntry("assignment", await MultipartFile.fromFile(file)),
]);
}
```

Comment: This works. Unlike many accepted answers out there.

Comment: what if we have other entries as well ????

Comment: Tks bro, this worked for me!!!

Comment: @ArslanKaleem It's for other persons who's still looking for your answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77724945/11485806

Answer (score 0):

This works as well:

```
var formData = FormData();
for (var file in filepath) {
  formData.files.add(MapEntry("assignment", 
  MultipartFile.fromFileSync(file)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final httpDio = Dio();
  final formData = dio.FormData.fromMap({
    "data": "{}",
    "File": await dio.MultipartFile.fromFile(
        filePath,
        filename: filePath.toString().split("/").last,
        contentType: MediaType('image', 'jpg'),
      ),
    "type": "image/jpg"
  });

final dio.Response response = await httpDio.post(
      Strings.baseUrl +"/"+ Strings.documentUpload,
      data: formData,
      options: dio.Options(
        headers: {
          "RequestVerificationToken": box.read(Keys.token),
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
         }
        )
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({"assignment": uploadList});
```

to

```
FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({"assignment": uploadList}, ListFormat.multiCompatible);
```

FormData.fromMap factory use ListFormat.multi by default. Using multiCompatible option makes your request like foo[]=value instead of foo=value according to ListFormat enum source code defination.

Here is the related section of ListFormat enum:

```
/// Multiple parameter instances rather than multiple values.
/// e.g. (foo=value&foo=another_value)
multi,

/// Forward compatibility.
/// e.g. (foo[]=value&foo[]=another_value)
multiCompatible,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> filePathList = [];

filePathList.add(imageFile.path.toString());

var formData = FormData.fromMap({
  "item_type": itemType,
  "title": title,
  "description": description,
  "price": price,
  "quantity": quantity,
  "location": location,
  "pickup_time": pickupTime,
}, ListFormat.multiCompatible);

for (var file in filePathList) {
  formData.files.addAll([
    MapEntry("images[]", await MultipartFile.fromFile(file, filename: file.split('/').last)),
  ]);
}
```