# Multipe images uploading on server not working flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to upload multiple images to server but always get issues. I tried some other solutions as well but not working.

```
saveImages() async {
    // string to uri
    Uri uri = Uri.parse('http://100.0.50.10:8000/API/AddImageCarSale/Post');

// create multipart request
    MultipartRequest request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
    if (images != null) {
      for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        ByteData byteData = await images[i].getByteData();
        List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

        MultipartFile multipartFile = MultipartFile.fromBytes(
          'photo', //key of the api
          imageData,
          filename: images[i].name,
          contentType: MediaType("image",
              "jpg"), //this is not nessessory variable. if this getting error, erase the line.
        );
        request.fields['PhoneNo'] = '1122';
        request.fields['VehicleNo'] = '1234';
// add file to multipart
        request.files.add(multipartFile);
// send
        var response = await request.send();
      }
    }
  }
```

My error is

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Can't finalize a finalized Request.
E/flutter (11521): #0      BaseRequest.finalize (package:http/src/base_request.dart:104:20)
E/flutter (11521): #1      MultipartRequest.finalize (package:http/src/multipart_request.dart:92:11)
E/flutter (11521): #2      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:28:26)
E/flutter (11521): #3      BaseRequest.send (package:http/src/base_request.dart:119:35)
E/flutter (11521): #4      _SellerFormState.savedNew (package:Autolog/pages/buySell/sellerForm.dart:361:38)
E/flutter (11521): 
E/flutter (11521): #5      _SellerFormState._buildBody. (package:Autolog/pages/buySell/sellerForm.dart:754:25)
E/flutter (11521): #6      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:992:19)
E/flutter (11521): #7      _InkResponseState.build. (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1098:38)
E/flutter (11521): #8      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:184:24)
E/flutter (11521): #9      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:524:11)
E/flutter (11521): #10     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:284:5)
E/flutter (11521): #11     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:256:7)
E/flutter (11521): #12     GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:158:27)
E/flutter (11521): #13     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:224:20)
E/flutter (11521): #14     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:200:22)
E/flutter (11521): #15     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:158:7)
E/flutter (11521): #16     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:104:7)
E/flutter (11521): #17     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:88:7)
E/flutter (11521): #18     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
E/flutter (11521): #19     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter (11521): #20     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter (11521): #21     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:267:10)
E/flutter (11521): #22     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:176:5)
E/flutter (11521):

Comment: try using dio package for flutter. Here's a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63263840/how-to-upload-multiple-images-files-in-flutter-using-dio

Comment: can you guide me if i have to add parameters inside formdata?

Comment: just add more properties in your map :   FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({"assignment": uploadList, "property_one": 1, "property_two": 2});

Comment: I have list <Asset> , it is not list<file>

Comment: tried multiple solutions getting error  Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Can't finalize a finalized MultipartFile.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new multipart request for every loop as multipart request gets finalized.
Try this modification and it should work.

```
    // string to uri
    Uri uri = Uri.parse('http://100.0.50.10:8000/API/AddImageCarSale/Post');

// create multipart request
    if (images != null) {
      for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        MultipartRequest request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
        ByteData byteData = await images[i].getByteData();
        List<int> imageData = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

        MultipartFile multipartFile = MultipartFile.fromBytes(
          'photo', //key of the api
          imageData,
          filename: images[i].name,
          contentType: MediaType("image",
              "jpg"), //this is not nessessory variable. if this getting error, erase the line.
        );
        request.fields['PhoneNo'] = '1122';
        request.fields['VehicleNo'] = '1234';
// add file to multipart
        request.files.add(multipartFile);
// send
        var response = await request.send();
      }
    }
  }
```